# Reading / Writing Strings to Binary Files

Tags: c++, string, file

I have been experiencing a bug for the past day that I have not been able to solve.

I have my first method which is for saving player data:

```
    bool Player::savePlayerData() {
    ofstream writeFile(getName() + ".bin", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    
    string writeData;

    writeData = formatEntityData() + "<" + formatLocationData() + "<" + formatInventory();

    writeFile.write(writeData.c_str(), writeData.length() + 1);

    writeFile.close();

    return true;
}
```

*Note: Assume that getName(), formatEntityData(), formatLocationData(), and formatInventory() return strings and are functional.*

Then I have my load player data method:

```
bool Player::loadPlayerData(string name) {
    ifstream readFile(name + ".bin", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::_Nocreate);
    if (readFile.good() && readFile.is_open()) {

        string data;
        getline(readFile, data, '\0');

        vector<string> str = split(data, '<');
        parseEntityData(str.at(0));
        parseLocationData(str.at(1));
        parseInventory(str.at(2));

        readFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    readFile.close();
    return false;
}
```

*Note: Assume that parseEntityData(), parseLocationData(), parseInventory() have string param, void returns and are functional*
*Note: Assume that split(string, char) takes in a string with a delim. char and splits into vector correctly*

---

So, here is what I am trying to accomplish (for purposes of simplicity lets assume getName() return "luke"):

•Create luke.bin

•Save string to luke.bin in binary

•Load data from luke.bin in form of a string

When I run the program is not properly reading the player data. Instead it is returning as if nothing is in the file. What am I doing wrong? Any tips, ideas, or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Code on brothers!

Comment: `it is normal ACSII text not that weird binary stuff` Well, you write normal ASCII text to it - why do you expect it to magically turn into "weird binary stuff", whatever that might be? `it is not properly reading the data in the file` What exactly do you mean by "not properly"? What results do you observe, what do you expect, and how do the two differ?

Comment: Typically when you open a binary file in notepad++ it gives seemingly random characters instead of the actual characters. However, the more important issue is that it is not reading the written data.

Answer (score 0):

> Typically when you open a binary file in notepad++ it gives seemingly
>   random characters

It depends on data. The string `"Hell world"` is the same in binary or text. Numbers will appear as text if they are text formatted.

Example of text format:

```
fout << 1234 << std::endl; //saved as "1234"
```

Example of binary data:

```
int i = 1234;
fout.write(&i, sizeof(i)); //saved as 2 bytes, big-endian or little endian binary
```

`ios::binary` stops translation of new line characters.

**When writing to file,** put the exact size:

```
writeFile.write(writeData.c_str(), writeData.length());
```

**When reading the file,**  `getline(fin, data, '\0');` will stop when it reaches zero or end of file. You should use EOF instead of zero. Better yet, use this method:

```
std::ifstream f(filename, ios::binary);
if (f.good())
{
    f.seekg(0, ios::end);
    size_t filesize = (size_t)f.tellg();
    f.seekg(0);

    std::string data(filesize, 0);
    f.read(&data[0], filesize);
    cout << data << endl;
    return true;
}
return false;
```